# Make a matrix with columns of higher order combinations of two or more vectors

Tags: r

Here is an example:

```
x1 = runif(10, -1, 1) 
x2 = runif(10, -1, 1) 
transformed = as.matrix(data.frame(x1 = x1, x2 = x2, x1x2 = x1*x2, x1squared
= x1^2, x2squared = x2^2))
```

This is not a problem, but what if I wanted all combinations of 3 vectors, then the columns would be:

x1, x2, x3, x1*x2, x1*x3, x2*x3, x1^2, x2^2, x3^2, x1*x2*x3, x1^2*x2*x3...

Is there an automatic way of obtaining such a matrix? Btw, I should know which column is which in some way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can also try using `model.matrix` which generates orthogonal polynomials (not simple polynomials) and is used by R to interpret its handy `formula` interface. Details about the available options [here](http://data.princeton.edu/R/linearModels.html):

```
x1 <- rnorm(20)
x2 <- rnorm(20)
x3 <- rnorm(20)
## compute all combos of polynomials up to degree 3
model.matrix(~ poly(x1, 3) * poly(x2, 3) * poly(x3, 3))
```

**EDIT:** Fixed after comment by @DavidArenburg below

Answer (score 1):

May be you can try:

```
 res <- do.call(`polym`, c(dat1, degree=3, raw=TRUE))
```

The column names suggest whether it is higher-order multiplication of itself, multiplied with other column or not. For example, colname `1.0.0` suggest the first column of `dat1` without any modification, while `2.0.0` is second-order multiplication of first column. where as `1.1.0` suggests 1st and 2nd column of original dataset multiplied together.

```
  head(res,3)
  #        1.0.0     2.0.0       3.0.0       0.1.0       1.1.0       2.1.0
  #[1,]  0.8296121 0.6882562  0.57098567 -0.08451645 -0.07011587 -0.05816897
  #[2,]  0.8741508 0.7641397  0.66797332  0.43822450  0.38307431  0.33486473
  #[3,] -0.4277209 0.1829452 -0.07824949  0.86934449 -0.37183684  0.15904240
  #       0.2.0        1.2.0         0.3.0      0.0.1      1.0.1      2.0.1
  #[1,] 0.00714303  0.005925944 -0.0006037035  0.8080628  0.6703786  0.5561542
  #[2,] 0.19204072  0.167872550  0.0841569471 -0.7225797 -0.6316436 -0.5521518
  #[3,] 0.75575985 -0.323254306  0.6570156644  0.9777835 -0.4182185  0.1788808
  #       0.1.1       1.1.1        0.2.1     0.0.2      1.0.2       0.1.2
  #[1,] -0.0682946 -0.05665802  0.005772017 0.6529654  0.5417080 -0.05518632
  #[2,] -0.3166521 -0.27680171 -0.138764716 0.5221214  0.4564128  0.22880638
  #[3,]  0.8500307 -0.36357591  0.738969479 0.9560605 -0.4089271  0.83114592
  #       0.0.3
  #[1,]  0.5276371
  #[2,] -0.3772743
  #[3,]  0.9348201

 head(dat1[,1]^2,3)
 #[1] 0.6882562 0.7641397 0.1829452

  head(dat1[,1]*dat1[,2],3)
 #[1] -0.07011587  0.38307431 -0.37183684


  head(dat1[,1]*dat1[,2]*dat1[,3],3)
 #[1] -0.05665802 -0.27680171 -0.36357591
```

#### data

```
set.seed(42)
dat1 <- data.frame(x1=runif(10,-1,1), x2=runif(10,-1,1), x3=runif(10,-1,1))
```